# How to change the handle size of a materialise css nouislider?

Tags: materialize, nouislider

I want to change the size and shape(from rectangle to circle) of the handles of my nouislider. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS you will find the attribute `.noUi-handle`. You can style the handles the way you like. Please see the [documentation](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/) for more information.